# How to return multiple results using Javascript filter method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

One quick question regarding filter method. 
Is it possible to return multiple values using JavaScript filter method
So, I was wondering is it possible to loop through json and filter values using something like this...

```
var arr = [{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'johnson@mail.com',
    age: 25,
    address: 'USA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    email: 'tom@mail.com',
    age: 35,
    address: 'England'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    email: 'mark@mail.com',
    age: 28,
    address: 'England'
  }
];

// filter array by name Mark and Tom
const result = arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el.name === 'Mark' && el.name ==='Tom';
});
```

And end result would be something like this:

```
  [Object { name: "Mark", email: "mark@mail.com", age: 28, address: "England" },{ name: "Tom", email: "tom@mail.com", age: 35, address: "England" }]
```

Is something like this possible and if not what is your best method/approach?

Comment: Well minus the typo of the missing `===`,  you are saying `name` has to equal `"mark"` *AND* `"tom"`..... I doubt one string can equal two things. So instead of AND what should it be?

Comment: @epascarello thank you. You are right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function you pass to `filter`, you want to check if the name equals "Mark" **OR** "Tom".  That will return an array with the two objects that match.

```js
var arr=[{name:'John',email:'johnson@mail.com',age:25,address:'USA'},{name:'Tom',email:'tom@mail.com',age:35,address:'England'},{name:'Mark',email:'mark@mail.com',age:28,address:'England'}]

// filter array by name Mark and Tom
const result = arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el.name === 'Mark' || el.name === 'Tom';
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Yep, that was it . I can't believe that I've miss something like this :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`filters` take an array and returns a subset array of the elements matching some condition.

You have to provide a function that is `true` for the elements you want to get, and `false` for the others.

The only missing thing in your function is that you need to use `||` (logical OR) instead of `&&` (and)

```
const result = arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el.name === 'Mark' || el.name === 'Tom';
});
```

because an element can have its name equals to Mark OR Tom, but no element has it's name equals to Mark AND Tom at the same time.

Comment: @epascarello for some reason I created another answer while correcting the typo, instead of fixing the existing one. I deleted the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [{
  name: 'John',
  email: 'johnson@mail.com',
  age: 25,
  address: 'USA'
}, {
  name: 'Tom',
  email: 'tom@mail.com',
  age: 35,
  address: 'England'
}, {
  name: 'Mark',
  email: 'mark@mail.com',
  age: 28,
  address: 'England'
}];

const selectedNames = ["Mark", "Tom"];

const result = arr.filter(({
  name
}) => selectedNames.includes(name));

console.log(result);
```